# Muliple tag search in advance search not working in alfresco

Tags: tags, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've added the aspect cm:taggable in the advanced search for search by tags. When the user select one tag to search, Alfresco returns all documents that have the tag selected, but when the users select two or more tags, Alfresco returns nothing.

Using alfresco community edition 4.2.c

Comment: do you want to use OR or AND if you provide more then 1 tag in your query?

Comment: @alfrescian I want to use AND

Comment: @yuvaraj What you have configured for one tag search? in my case one tag search is not working.

Comment: @Sanjay Patel solved this issue by re-coding getSearchResults(params) in search.lib.js by adding an entry of tags in query.

Answer (score 1):

There is a required control-param value to get this to work in most recent versions of alfresco. Its documented in:

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms#category.ftl

But the bottom line is in the appearance setting of the form configuration you need a mode set for this to work on the category.ftl:

```
<field id="cm:taggable">
       <control>
           <control-param name="compactMode">true</control-param>
           <control-param name="params">aspect=cm:taggable</control-param>
           <control-param name="createNewItemUri">/api/tag/workspace/SpacesStore</control-param>
           <control-param name="createNewItemIcon">tag</control-param>
           <control-param name="mode">AND</control-param> <!-- AND or OR -->
      </control>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i added

```
   <show id="cm:taggable" for-mode="edit" force="true" />
    <field id="cm:taggable">
              <control>
                 <control-param name="compactMode">true</control-param>
                 <control-param name="params">aspect=cm:taggable</control-param>
                 <control-param name="createNewItemUri">/api/tag/workspace/SpacesStore</control-param>
                 <control-param name="createNewItemIcon">tag</control-param>
              </control>
           </field>
```

I can now search by tags but it gives me 0 results when I try.  If I enter the tagname as a keyword, the content with attached tags are showing.

E.G: I have some files with a tag "invoice" . When I do an advanced search on tag invoice it gives 0 results, but when I enter it as a keyword, the content with the tag "invoice" is shows. 
I don't know what the reason is, maybe this can help you in any possible way

regards

Comment: I did all same like you, same problem, 0 results when searching with multiple tags.

Comment: i have same problem..any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration for this, solved this issue by re-coding getSearchResults(params) in search.lib.js by adding an entry of tags in query.